# rust z3 version >= v 0.10.0 ast.Bool::and function

Tags: rust, boolean, z3, smt

Rust  z3
When the version of z3 is "v.0.4.0", we could use Bool::and function to represents the result of the AND of two bool variables.
But in version >= "v.0.10.0",it went wrong.
"no method named 'and' found for struct 'z3::ast::Bool<'_>' in the current scope" occurs when used and function " boolVar1.and(&[&boolVar2])".
When see the source code, when can see the 'and' func in here

```
"
varop! {
        and(Z3_mk_and, Self);
        or(Z3_mk_or, Self);
    }
"
```

How can i use the func 'and' now?

z3 version v.0.10.0

```
varop! {
    and(Z3_mk_and, Self);
    or(Z3_mk_or, Self);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In [z3-0.4.0](https://docs.rs/z3/0.4.0/z3/ast/struct.Bool.html), the signature of `Bool::and` was as follows:

```rust
pub fn and(&self, other: &[&Self]) -> Self
```

However, it was changed in [z3-0.6.0](https://docs.rs/z3/0.6.0/z3/ast/struct.Bool.html) to

```rust
pub fn and(context: &'ctx Context, values: &[&Self]) -> Self
```

The usage is as follows:

```
let exp1: Bool = ... ;
let exp2: Bool = ... ;
let and_exp = exp1.and(&[&exp2]);         // for version < z3-0.6.0
let and_exp = Bool::and(&[&exp1, &exp2]); // for version >= z3-0.6.0
```